# Google Form Responses Randomly Stop Posting to Response Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This has happened multiple times to several of my Forms/Response Spreadsheets...

Randomly, Google Forms will stop posting responses to the Response Spreadsheet. I can tell this is occurring because the number of responses is greater than the number of rows in the spreadsheet (-1 because of the row that contains the column headers). No changes have been made to the Spreadsheets when this happens; no permissions were changed, nothing happens except that a Form was submitted, and responses stop posting to the Spreadsheet.

I have tried `Spreadsheet.flush()` but this didn't have any effect. The only fix I've been able to come up with is *unlinking* the Form, then creating a *new* Response Spreadsheet. However, I have to set up all my attached Script Projects every time this occurs, and it's becoming an annoyance. The only decent thing about this is that when I do create the new Response Spreadsheet, all of the responses are correctly (re-)posted to the Spreadsheet.

So, **three questions**:

1. Why might Google Forms stop posting responses to the Response Spreadsheet?
2. Is this a known issue and I just can't find it on the issue tracker?
3. Is there any workaround to quickly fix this issue (something like `Spreadsheet.flush()`)?

**Edit**: My guess is that Google's servers temporarily fall behind (queue too long?), and perhaps the form response is lost (temporarily or permanently depending on the load?). Permanent loss seems to break the Form-Spreadsheet link entirely.

For the record, **onFormSubmit triggers still run** as they should, but other post-processing tasks that rely on the data actually being present in the Spreadsheet do *not* (because the data is not there of course).

Comment: Google Forms (free app accounts) users in our company complain about no-shows. Currently, I assume forms eventually turn up in the ss, but I'll audit this a bit closely over a few weeks to see. I did some tests this weekend (when Forms seemed particularly bad) with onFormSubmit with 'processed' tokens placed in the adjacent column; unlike you, I noticed a couple of tokens from 60 submits were not present, even after the data eventually turned up.  But I will go check given your feedback. I found one current on-topic post:http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/wy8WXHIz_kg/NeSC5Mq3NXcJ

Comment: Yes that seems to be from last week, and as you say Forms were generally misbehaving. However, this has been an ongoing problem at my work for several months in fact, if that helps distinguish potential underlying problems. Honestly there seems to be a large lack of cohesion to Spreadsheets in general. Often times I find that `importRange` ceases to function randomly with no changes made the Spreadsheet, nor Form submission to the Sheet it is importing from. There are other cases as well, this case and `importRange` are the most prominent in my experience.

Comment: Was there ever a solution found to this issue, besides re-linking the spreadsheet each time?